# Formatar número no reportviewer?

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer

Estou tentando formatar um numero no `ReportViewer` e não estou conseguindo, pra isso estou tentando usar a função `Format` do `TextBox` no `ReportViewer`. O número é um código e estou tentando preencher com 3 zeros à esquerda. Estou tentando assim: `=FormatNumber(Fields!terminal.Value.codigo, String.Format("{N:000}"))`, mas não está funcionando. Como fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

O correto seria:

```
Format(Fields!terminal.Value.codigo, "0000");
```

***Referencias:***

- [Adding Style and Formatting to a ReportViewer Report](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252080(VS.80).aspx)
- [Utilizando expressões no Report Viewer](http://www.andrealveslima.com.br/blog/index.php/2015/04/15/utilizando-expressoes-no-report-viewer/)